# How do big websites implement brute force login protection?

Tags: security, brute-force, login-system

So I have read some articles on how to implement a brute force login protection, but all of them seem to have some sort of drawback, so heres the approaches I found:

1. Captcha 
   Since there are "captcha solvers", I don't think this is very efficient.
2. Ban IP address based on # of failed login attempts 
   Well this could lead to a lot extra work on the help desk and malicious attackers can intentionally lock out innocent clients by faking their ip
3. lock out account for # of failed login attempts 
   Same reason as above, malicious attackers can lock out clients
4. honey pot 
   Well, I don't think this will work for any experienced hackers
5. device cookies 
   This is by far the best one I have found, it does increase security but is not enough by itself.

So if all above techniques have some degree of drawbacks, how do big sites like google, freelancer implement BFP? Is it just a combination of everything, or is there something I missed out?

Besides, can attackers figure out usernames from abusing the signup username check?

Comment: It's an arms race. Inevitably, attackers will target any technique that becomes successful (e.g. CAPTCHAs). Device cookies have been around for only a couple of years and are hardly widely used, hence the lower interest in *breaking* them.